Directional animations on HTMX swap trouble
I'm trying to swap in the content with an animation based on if the user has clicked next or previous.
If the user has clicked next, the current content should scroll up and fade out and new content to come in from below.
And vice versa, if the user clicks previous, the current content should scroll down and fade out and the new content from above.
I can easily achieve an animation in one direction, but not both ways.
I've tried to achieve this with the htmx-settle class, listening for clicks and adding classes, setting timeouts and adding classes before and after requests. Something that seems super simple on paper but I haven't found a solution yet.
Even when I thought I cracked it, it's as though the Dom ignored the CSS of a class that I added on the new content.
Any ideas?

Please provide example code of what have you tried so far. Tx
